# Test a method using the org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I have a class method that I would like test

```
public class EllaDtoConverter {


    private static void convertToIp( final IrisBo irisBo, EllaRequestDto request ) {

        if( nonNull( irisBo.getDevice() ) ) {
            request.setIp( irisBo.getDevice().getIpAddress() );
        }
    }
}
```

My test is provided

```
@Test
public void testConvertToIp() {

    assertNotNull( validIrisBo.getDevice() );
    assertNotNull( validIrisBo.getDevice().getIpAddress() );

    EllaRequestDto ellaRequestDto = new EllaRequestDto();

    ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod( ellaRequestDto, "setIp", validIrisBo.getDevice().getIpAddress() );
}
```

Does it okay to leave it like this or I have a better option to test?

Comment: Is it possible to learn why does this question receive downvote so I won't ask similar question later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing a separate test for `private` method increases the confidence in the code than it should not be a `private` method. `private` methods are implementation details and should be tested through the interface of the class.

In case you don't want to extract this `private` method to make it visible e.g. as a separate class, you can use the default visibility modifier to at least avoid Java reflection:

```
public class EllaDtoConverter {
    static void convertToIp( final IrisBo irisBo, EllaRequestDto request ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the advice is good, but, I can't do anything with the source code ATM. So, based on the scope provided, do you have any other suggestion/ advise?